# Show PowerPoint window after hiding it - VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've hidden a PowerPoint presentation using the `open`and `withwindow` method as described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentations-open-method-powerpoint

Now I need to make the window reappear, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

found the answer. just need to use `NewWindow`